# Excel chart tabs are showing up as blank

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

All of my Excel 2003 chart tabs are showing up as blank. This includes both newly created chart tabs and chart tabs in existing spreadsheets, as well as both pivot table charts and regular charts.

Screenshot:
[image: Blank Excel tab]

Oddly, charts that are on a regular worksheet tab show up fine -- only charts in their own tab are affected.

I've run Excel Diagnostics and they found no problems.

I have verified that Excel Options > Advanced > Display Option > Objects is set to All for each of the spreadsheets.

How do I make chart tabs work again?

Comment: If you change their location back to another worksheet do they return?  Or once they're gone, are they gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Office fixed the issue. I suspect it may have been related to print spooler troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Select a different printer to change the appearance / visibility of contents in the chart tabs.

Excel chart tabs (where the content is only a chart) use the printer settings to render the image.  Other tabs do not until print preview is selected.